# MarianMTModel stops translating on encountering “-” character

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I’m trying to translate simple text from Polish to English:

“Życie nigdy się nie kończy – przygotuj się zatem na ciąg dalszy. Zasilany twoją energią zegarek z widocznym mechanizmem dopasuje się do ciebie..”

The model behaves strangely, when it encounters the `-` char it stops translating only returning the translation of what precedes the `-` char.
When I move this char the translation always ends before it.

After further investigation, the model returns the generated ids:
`tensor([[63429, 7157, 522, 10126, 15, 0]])`

when decoded:
`'<pad> Life never ends </s>'`.

Surprisingly, when I use `num_beams` set to 2 instead of 1 I get a good result. The problem is that because of time constraints I can't use `num_beams=2`

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: What is the tokenized output ? If you HF transformers and use pipelines, get rid of pipes and instantiate and call tokenizer and model separately, you can debug from that. My first guess (and idk why) would be that text input could be mapped to an EOS token ?

Comment: @null, you're right, it returns `</s>` token, generated ids: `tensor([[63429,  7157,   522, 10126,    15,     0]])` and when decoded: `'<pad> Life never ends </s>'`. Surprisingly, when I use `num_beams` set to 2 instead of 1 I get a good result. The problem is that because of time constraints I can't use `num_beams=2`